# Installing split AC's outdoot unit in a cool place

Tags: cooling

I wonder if it would be efficient if a split AC's outdoor unit is installed 8 feet underground in a well with ventilation will be any efficient due to the constant temperature underground all year round?

Comment: Are you heating the internal space or cooling?

Comment: google "heat pump system"

Comment: Well? Even if it is dry at the moment.  Is this unit waterproof?

Comment: no, the unit is not water proof, but should I worry if its just 8 feet underground with enough ventilation?

Comment: @SolarMike I am cooling the internal space

Comment: So google "heat pump system" as suggested and also look at using a water pipe under-ground to be part of the heat exchanger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my opinion that's an interesting sollution. And it should work better.

[working model](http://www.aireacondicionadonet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/funcionamiento-aire-acondicionado.png)

The problem I see is if your AC unit is strong enough. I mean that you should check the strength of air flow from the AC to the compressor.

However if you are only talking about efficency ONLY than it should work better.

[house](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vpSwlQKMg8Y/maxresdefault.jpg)

In the diagram you can't see but ambient temperature for outside tubes is also important and it affects the system, however as I told previously, the problem is the airflow strength and the 16 feet distance.